# python 3.5 no print output to screen

Tags: printing, python-3.5

Using Python 3.5  I have created code to process a file and write output to another file. Following is relevant code;

```
with open('2016_01_22_Investor_Companies_stops.txt','r') as stops_Investor_Companies:
    stops_Investor_Companies = stops_Investor_Companies.read()
    stops_Investor_Companies = nltk.word_tokenize(stops_Investor_Companies)
    stops_Investor_Companies= [w.lower() for w in stops_Investor_Companies]
    stops_Investor_Companies = str(stops_Investor_Companies)
    outfile = open ('stops_Investor_Companies_cln.txt', 'w')
    outfile.write(stops_Investor_Companies)
print ('1. Investor Companies')
print (' ')
with open('stops_Investor_Companies_cln.txt','r') as fin:
    print(fin.read())
print (' ')
```

The result is that the  text `1. Investor Companies` prints to the screen but the file `stops_Investor_Companies_cln.txt` is not printed to the screen.

However, I can print  the file `stops_Investor_Companies_cln.txt` to the screen using same code snippet as a separate script;

```
with open('stops_Investor_Companies_cln.txt','r') as fin:
    print(fin.read())
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not closing the file before opening it again. Data is flushed in file only after you close it.

Try closing the file before opening it again:-

```
outfile = open ('stops_Investor_Companies_cln.txt', 'w')
outfile.write(stops_Investor_Companies)
outfile.close()
```

Or you can use one more with option to open the file so that closing of file is taken care of...

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't closed the file before opening it again, you're not seeing the new data. What you should do is use another with statement when you open the file for writing so it gets closed properly.